# How to remove all but checked nodes and their parents in a treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

I have a `TreeView` that contains any number of nodes. Users can check any of the nodes in the `TreeView` and as soon as they click a button I want to prune everything but the checked nodes and their parents. I've got the button all setup and it calls a method that should prune the nodes, the issue I am having is the logic behind the pruning. Even pseudo code would be helpful. I know it needs to be recursive and should start from the outer most nodes and work my way up, but I can't seem to come up with the recursion.

I don't care if it prunes the `TreeView` directly or if it creates a new `List<TreeNode>` that i can bind to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

**Solution:** The solution by InBetween fixed my logic problem, but there was still one more issue. You have to delete nodes from their parent. So you can't just go do `TreeView.Remove(node)` you have to do `ParentNode.ChildNodes.Remove(node)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes looking at a problem from another point of view helps.

Why dont you first change the logic of how the tree manages item checking if possible:

If the user checks an item you will not delete either the item nor its parents. Therefore when the user checks an item check every item up the tree until you get to the selected item's root item. That is easy to implement.

Now when you prune you just have to traverse the tree (starting from root items and moving down the tree) looking for non checked items. You can delete these and therefore all the items hanging from it without having to look if there are selected items down that branch.

Maybe this option is not valid due to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using your logic and making it so whenever a checkbox is checked then it's parent was checked. When i load the treeview i have it check all the parents of the ones that were saved in the DB and then i just remove all that aren't checked.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar, where if a child was clicked, the parent was autoselected. So I guess this might help, as it would first select all parents, and then you can clean by looking for selected (from the top):

```
    private void RecursiveCheckNodesDown(TreeNodeCollection tree, bool checkedFlag)
    {
        if (tree != null) 
            foreach (TreeNode node in tree)
                RecursiveCheckNodesDown(node.Nodes, node.Checked = checkedFlag);
    }

    private void RecursiveCheckNodesUp(TreeNode node, bool checkedFlag)
    {
        if( node != null )
            RecursiveCheckNodesUp(node.Parent, node.Checked = checkedFlag);
    }

    private void SomeTreeBeginUpdate()
    {
        SomeTree.BeginUpdate();
        SomeTree.AfterCheck -= SomeTree_AfterCheck;
    }

    private void SomeTreeEndUpdate()
    {
        SomeTree.AfterCheck += SomeTree_AfterCheck;
        SomeTree.EndUpdate();
    }

    private void SomeTree_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeTreeBeginUpdate();
        RecursiveCheckNodesDown(e.Node.Nodes, e.Node.Checked);
        if( e.Node.Checked )
            RecursiveCheckNodesUp(e.Node.Parent, e.Node.Checked);
        SomeTreeEndUpdate();
    }

    this.SomeTree.AfterCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.SomeTree_AfterCheck);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I noticed you are using `Windows.Forms` unless I don't understand it correctly, can't I not use that with an ASP.net application?

Answer (score 0):

this can by done by implementing a depth-first-search ...

something like

```
//pseudocode
bool prune(treenode t)
{
   bool mayNotDeleteThisNode=t.isChecked;
   foreach(treenode c in t.childnodes)
   {
      if(prune(c)) mayNotDeleteThisNode=true;
   }

   if(!mayNotDeleteThisNode)
   {
      delete(t)
   }

   return mayNotDeleteThisNode;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if you can delete a node while enumerating through the node collection. Wont delete remove the node from the cildNodes and therefore modify the collection? I think you have to do it with conventional loops or just create a new tree with the selected nodes.

Comment: therefore ... pseudocode ... delete also could be implemented as a function that stores those pending delete operations somehow, to be executed after the tree has been traversed